# Is tacrolimus carcinogenic and if so, what causes it to be?

Tags: dermatology, cancer, risks, topical-cream-gel, vitiligo

The FDA issued a health warning <sup>1</sup> regarding the possible cancer risks of tacrolimus ointment, however, British dermatologists<sup>2</sup> don't consider this a significant concern and they are increasingly recommending the use of this drug, for example for the treatment of vitiligo.

Is tacrolimus cancerous and if so, what causes it to be?

---

<sup>*1. [https://www.fda.gov/drugs/postmarket-drug-safety-information-patients-and-providers/tacrolimus-marketed-protopic-ointment-information](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacrolimus)*</sup>
<sup>*2. https://web.archive.org/web/20131213072822/http://www.bad.org.uk/Portals/_Bad/Guidelines/Position%20Statements%20%26%20Other%20Documents/Advice%20re%20topical%20tacrolimus.pdf*</sup>